# How does handover from wifi to gprs work?

Tags: wi-fi, calls, gprs

I start a google hangouts call and I'm connected to wifi.
Then when I leave home, the call is handed over from wifi to GPRS.
How is this done? 
Does the app help doing the handover or is this transparent to the app?

When switching to GPRS, the phone gets a new ip address, so a new connection is necessary, right?